# Can not pass the props correctly to another component from the component where table mapped with data, how to solve this?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, mern

`console.log(selectedId)` produces multiple ids, hence can't get or put a request.

Student's List Component(selectedstanard passed from parent component) :

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import EditStudent from "./EditStudent.jsx";

axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;

const StudentsList = ({ selectedStandard }) => {
  const [students, setStudents] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchStudentsByStandard = async () => {
      try {
        const { data } = await axios.get(
          `http://localhost:4000/students/${selectedStandard}`,
          { withCredentials: true }
        );
        setStudents(data.students);
        console.log(data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching students:", error);
      }
    };

    if (selectedStandard) {
      fetchStudentsByStandard();
    }
  }, [selectedStandard]);

  const handleEdit = (studentId) => {
    console.log(`Editing student with ID: ${studentId}`);
  };

  return (
    <div className="overflow-x-auto">
      <h2 className="text-2xl font-semibold text-blue-800 text-center mb-2">
        Standard - {selectedStandard}
      </h2>
      <table className="min-w-full divide-y divide-gray-200">
        <thead className="text-xs bg-gray-50 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400">
          <tr>
            <th className="px-3 py-2 sm:px-6 sm:py-3">Student Name</th>
            <th className="px-3 py-2 sm:px-6 sm:py-3">Roll Number</th>
            <th className="px-3 py-2 sm:px-6 sm:py-3">Birthdate</th>
            <th className="px-3 py-2 sm:px-6 sm:py-3">UID</th>
            <th className="px-3 py-2 sm:px-6 sm:py-3">Contact</th>
            <th className="px-3 py-2 sm:px-6 sm:py-3">Address</th>
            <th className="px-3 py-2 sm:px-6 sm:py-3">Operations</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody className="text-sm bg-white divide-y divide-gray-200 dark:bg-gray-800 dark:divide-gray-700">
          {students.map((student) => (
            <tr className="hover:bg-gray-50 dark:hover:bg-gray-600">
              <td className="px-3 py-2 sm:px-6 sm:py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                {student.studentname}
              </td>
              <td className="px-3 py-2 sm:px-6 sm:py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                {student.rollnumber}
              </td>
              <td className="px-3 py-2 sm:px-6 sm:py-4">{student.birthdate}</td>
              <td className="px-3 py-2 sm:px-6 sm:py-4">{student.uid}</td>
              <td className="px-3 py-2 sm:px-6 sm:py-4">{student.contact}</td>
              <td className="px-3 py-2 sm:px-6 sm:py-4">{student.address}</td>
              <td className="px-3 py-2 sm:px-6 sm:py-4 flex justify-center">
                <EditStudent
                  id={student._id}
                />

                <button className="px-3 py-1 bg-red-500 text-white rounded-md hover:bg-red-600">
                  Delete
                </button>
              </td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
};

export default StudentsList;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
This is EditStudent :

import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Modal } from 'flowbite-react';
import { ToastContainer, toast } from 'react-toastify';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';

const EditStudent = ({ id, handleEdit }) => {
  const [openModal, setOpenModal] = useState(false);
  const [selectedId, setSelectedId] = useState(id);
  const [studentname, setStudentname] = useState('');
  const [standard, setStandard] = useState('');
  const [rollnumber, setRollnumber] = useState('');
  const [birthdate, setBirthdate] = useState('');
  const [address, setAddress] = useState('');
  const [phonenumber, setPhonenumber] = useState('');
  const [uid, setUid] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    const getStudentData = async () => {
      try {
        const { data } = await axios.get(`http://localhost:4000/students/one/${selectedId}`);
        // Set the initial state with the received data
        setStudentname(data.studentname);
        setStandard(data.standard);
        setRollnumber(data.rollnumber);
        setBirthdate(data.birthdate);
        setPhonenumber(data.phonenumber);
        setUid(data.uid);
        setAddress(data.address);
        console.log(selectedId);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching student data', error);
      }
    };if (selectedId) {
      getStudentData();
    }
  }, [selectedId]);

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  try {
    await axios.put(`http://localhost:4000/students/edit/${selectedId}`, {
      studentname,
      standard,
      rollnumber,
      birthdate,
      address,
      phonenumber,
      uid,
    });

    const message = 'Student updated successfully';
    console.log(message);

    toast.success(message, {
      position: 'bottom-right',
      autoClose: 4000,
      hideProgressBar: false,
      closeOnClick: true,
      pauseOnHover: true,
    });
    handleEdit(selectedId);
    onClose();
    setOpenModal(false);
  } catch (error) {
      if (error.response) {
        toast.error(error.response.data.message);
      } else if (error.request) {
        console.error(error.request);
        toast.error('Request error: Please try again later.');
      } else {
        console.error('Error', error.message);
        toast.error('An unexpected error occurred.');
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
    <button
        className="rounded-md px-3 py-2 bg-blue-800 text-sm font-bold text-gray-200 hover:bg-gray-700"
        onClick={() => setOpenModal(true)}
      >
        Edit
      </button>
      <Modal dismissible show={openModal} onClose={() => setOpenModal(false)}>
        <Modal.Header className="bg-red-100">Edit Student</Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="w-full max-w-lg ">
            <div className="flex flex-wrap -mx-3 mb-6">
              <div className="w-full md:w-1/2 px-3 mb-6 md:mb-0">
                <label
                  className="block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2"
                  htmlFor="name"
                >
                  Name
                </label>
                <input
              className="appearance-none block w-full bg-gray-200 text-gray-700 border border-gray-200 rounded py-3 px-4 mb-3 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white"
              id="name"
              name="name"
              type="text"
              value={studentname}
              onChange={(e) => setStudentname(e.target.value)}
            />
              </div>
              <div className="w-full md:w-1/2 px-3">
                <label
                  className="block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2"
                  htmlFor="standard"
                >
                  Standard
                </label>
                <input
                  className="appearance-none block w-full bg-gray-200 text-gray-700 border border-gray-200 rounded py-3 px-4 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-gray-500"
                  id="standard"
                  name="standard"
                  type="number"
                  value={standard}
                  onChange={(e) => setStandard(e.target.value)}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="flex flex-wrap -mx-3 mb-6">
              <div className="w-full md:w-1/2 px-3 mb-6 md:mb-0">
                <label
                  className="block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2"
                  htmlFor="rollnumber"
                >
                  Roll Number
                </label>
                <input
                  className="appearance-none block w-full bg-gray-200 text-gray-700 border border-gray-200 rounded py-3 px-4 mb-3 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white"
                  id="rollnumber"
                  name="rollnumber"
                  type="text"
                  value={rollnumber}
                  onChange={(e)=> setRollnumber(e.target.value)}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="w-full md:w-1/2 px-3">
                <label
                  className="block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2"
                  htmlFor="birthdate"
                >
                  Birthdate
                </label>
                <input
                  className="appearance-none block w-full bg-gray-200 text-gray-700 border border-gray-200 rounded py-3 px-4 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-gray-500"
                  id="birthdate"
                  name="birthdate"
                  type="date"
                  value={birthdate}
                  onChange={(e) => setBirthdate(e.target.value)}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="flex flex-wrap -mx-3 mb-6">
              <div className="w-full md:w-1/2 px-3 mb-6 md:mb-0">
                <label
                  className="block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2"
                  htmlFor="uid"
                >
                  UID
                </label>
                <input
                  className="appearance-none block w-full bg-gray-200 text-gray-700 border border-gray-200 rounded py-3 px-4 mb-3 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white"
                  id="uid"
                  name="uid"
                  type="text"
                  value={uid}
                  onChange={(e) => setUid(e.target.value)}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="w-full md:w-1/2 px-3">
                <label
                  className="block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2"
                  htmlFor="phonenumber"
                >
                  Phone Number
                </label>
                <input
                  className="appearance-none block w-full bg-gray-200 text-gray-700 border border-gray-200 rounded py-3 px-4 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-gray-500"
                  id="phonenumber"
                  name="phonenumber"
                  type="text"
                  value={phonenumber}
                  onChange={(e) => setPhonenumber(e.target.value)}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="flex flex-wrap -mx-3 mb-6">
              <div className="w-full px-3">
                <label
                  className="block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2"
                  htmlFor="address"
                >
                  Address
                </label>
                <input
                  className="appearance-none block w-full bg-gray-200 text-gray-700 border border-gray-200 rounded py-3 px-4 mb-3 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-gray-500"
                  id="address"
                  type="text"
                  name="address"
                  value={address}
                  onChange={(e) => setAddress(e.target.value)}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
            <button
              type="submit"
              className="w-full bg-slate-700 text-white bg-primary-600 hover:bg-primary-700 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-primary-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-5 py-2.5 text-center dark:bg-primary-600 dark:hover:bg-primary-700 dark:focus:ring-primary-800"
            >
              Submit
            </button>
            <ToastContainer />
          </form>
        </Modal.Body>
      </Modal>
    </>
  )
}

export default EditStudent;
```

I want to edit a particular student when select with edit button with that student's id(mongodb).
current problem is when clicking the edit button, multiple students' ids of the selected standard are rendered which I am passing to the edit component, tried many solutions but with no success. Need assistance, thank you.

Comment: your current console.log(selectedId) happens multiple times because EditStudent component is being rendered for each user, therefor the useEffect is being called. could you please provide more information on what is the desired result & how it's different from what you have now

Comment: right now, while clicking a edit button of any student on StudentList component, multiply ids are passing to editStudent component, hence get and put request failing